# Disable Fancybox for specific images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, fancybox

I don't know Javascript but I'm using it to run Fancybox. There is no wordpress involved. It seems the way Fancybox works is by targeting any and all images, but for things like social media icons in my footer, I don't want targeted by Fancybox. Is there a simple way to turn off Fancybox on specific images?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
This is the Javascript I have pasted in my html.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        var addToAll = true;
        var gallery = true;
        var titlePosition = 'inside';
        $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.attr('title');
            var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
            var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
            $this.wrap(a);
        });
        if (gallery)
            $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            titlePosition: titlePosition
        });
    }); </script>
```

Comment: No. What is doing it is the `addToAll` set to `true`- if you look at the ternary later on, it selects all `img` when `addToAll` is true - if NOT true, it selects all images with `.fancybox` class set. So either change the `addToAll` to false, or modify the selector used (remove the ternary operator).

Comment: Change value of variable `addToAll` to false - now it adds fancybox for all img tags no matter what class they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `addToAll` from `true` to `false`. That way fancybox will just be added to images having the `.fancybox` class.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!